# How to configure Webpack to not pull content of imported Sass files to a source map?

Tags: node.js, webpack, sass, source-maps

I have a Sass file that imports Bootstrap and Font Awesome. 
They has been put on the of the file before my custom CSS class.
Here is the code:

**/src/scss/site.scss**

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
@import "~font-awesome/scss/font-awesome";

// Custom style sheet here
.my-custom-header{
    color:#F00
}
```

There is a source map after Webpack build but it includes the content of Bootstrap and font awesome.

Here what is look like in Browser:

[image]

When I tried to inspect a custom class it point to correct line number of origin source code but incorrect for generated source map because it has content of Bootstrap in the top.

My question is:

Is it possible to configure a output source map to keep the import statement and the content is  exact the same as actual source code.

Here what source map I'm expected.
**site.css.map**

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
@import "~font-awesome/scss/font-awesome";

// Custom style sheet here
.my-custom-header{
    color:#F00
}
```

Here my Webpack configuration:

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

const siteFile = [__dirname, 'src', 'scss', 'site'];
const outputPath = [__dirname, 'public', 'css'];

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        site: path.resolve(...siteFile),
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(...outputPath),
    },
    resolve: {
        // https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/720#issuecomment-268470989
        extensions: ['.scss']
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader', // Translates CSS into CommonJS modules
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'postcss-loader', // Run post css actions
                        options: {
                            plugins: () => {
                                // post css plugins, can be exported to postcss.config.js
                                return [
                                    require('precss'),
                                    require('autoprefixer')
                                ];
                            },
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'resolve-url-loader',
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader', // Compiles Sass to CSS, using node-sass by default
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    }
                ],
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|eot|ttf|woff2?)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: '[name].[ext]',
                            outputPath: '.' //relative to output
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: './[name].css' // relative to output
        }),
    ],
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
        compress: false,
        port: 8080,
    }
};
```

Here is a link to a repository of the example code.

[codesanook-examples-webpack](https://github.com/codesanook/Codesanook.Examples/tree/master/codesanook-examples-webpack)

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried SourceMapDevToolPlugin?
https://webpack.js.org/plugins/source-map-dev-tool-plugin/

You might need to create a vendor bundle for node modules stuff then you can ignore it from sourcemap.

Comment: I have found this tool before and try to setup but I could not make it. I will try it again and let you know the result. 

Thank you.

Comment: I have set up SourceMapDevToolPlugin but it could not fix the problem I have.

From this comment https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin/issues/123#issuecomment-419195560 telling us that the issue is from having Bootstrap at the top of Sass file.

I also verify by exclude Bootstrap and import my custom Sass file instead and the issue has gone.

However, SourceMapDevToolPlugin does not fix the problem but we can exclude Bootstrap to additional files or use CDN. 

FYI, importing our custom Sass files has no issue with source map.

Thanks for you suggestion again.